# NetCDF created with xarray and rioxarray

Tags: netcdf, gdal, python-xarray

I'm using xarray and rioxarray in python to create a DataSet then export to Netcdf. After saving, when I check the exported files with GDAL 3.2, I see the correct extent. However, when using GDAL >=3.4 (in a conda env) it seems that the extents are lost:

Here is the output with my system install GDAL:

```
micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.2.2, released 2021/03/05
micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo  NETCDF:"Kinneret_velocity.nc":v | grep -A 4 Corner                                   
Warning 1: dimension #2 (x) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #1 (y) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #0 (z) is not a Time or Vertical dimension.
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  735758.000, 3644806.000) ( 35d31'15.70"E, 32d54'57.98"N)
Lower Left  (  735758.000, 3621606.000) ( 35d30'54.46"E, 32d42'25.30"N)
Upper Right (  754558.000, 3644806.000) ( 35d43'18.74"E, 32d54'42.80"N)
Lower Right (  754558.000, 3621606.000) ( 35d42'55.82"E, 32d42'10.25"N)
```

However, in my conda environment, with a newer GDAL:

```
micha@RMS:Kinneret$ conda activate geo
(geo) micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.5.2, released 2022/09/02
(geo) micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo  NETCDF:"Kinneret_velocity.nc":v | grep -A 4 Corner
Warning 1: dimension #2 (x) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #1 (y) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #0 (z) is not a Time or Vertical dimension.
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,   58.0)
Upper Right (   47.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (   47.0,   58.0)
```

What do I need to add to the xarray Dataset so that the newer GDAL gets the extent?

(Note: In both cases all the "grid_mapping" metadata entries point to "spatial_ref", and the full spatial_ref details are available.)

Thanks

Comment: If you can read the data back in with xarray and everything is correct then this is just a `gdal` or `gdalinfo` issue. 3.2.1 is not the most recent version so I’d recommend updating. If the issue persists you’ll need to create a full [mre] with a file produced from code and then file an issue with gdal.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of months late to the party, but what I found is that the NetCDF format for geospatial information is quite sensitive to the attributes for each dimension.

Specifically, you're interested in the `standard_name` attribute, as defined in the [CF Conventions](https://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/cf-conventions.html#standard-name), and you should set it for both `x` and `y` coordinates.

For completion, consider the following (assuming the CRS you're using is metre-based, and that your `x` and `y` coordinates):

```py
ds.x.attrs["axis"] = "X"
ds.x.attrs["long_name"] = "x coordinate of projection"
ds.x.attrs["standard_name"] = "projection_x_coordinate"
ds.x.attrs["units"] = "metre"

ds.y.attrs["axis"] = "Y"
ds.y.attrs["long_name"] = "y coordinate of projection"
ds.y.attrs["standard_name"] = "projection_y_coordinate"
ds.y.attrs["units"] = "metre"
```